# Show Array of ImageView for 5 Seconds

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a TableLayout with an Array of ImageView then when I clicked on menuInflater it'll appear for five second and then hide and a countdown start.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

switch (item.getItemId()){

case R.id.txt1:
    handler = new Handler (this);
                Worker w = new Worker (handler);
               Thread t = new Thread (w);
               t.start();
     return true;
```

---

```
  protected int [] imgIds = {
    R.id.img_1,R.id.img_2,R.id.img_3,R.id.img_4,R.id.img_5,R.id.img_6,
    R.id.img_7,R.id.img_8,R.id.img_9,R.id.img_10,R.id.img_11,R.id.img_12,
   };

public class Worker implements Runnable{

private Handler h;

public Worker (Handler h)
{
this.h = h;
}

@Override
public void run() {

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    imgIds.setsetVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
h.postDelayed(Worker,1000);
 }   
 }
```

And then the ImageView hide and start the Game.

**This Code is wrong so If anybody can help me.**

Comment: But How? I need to create a new class or in the same?

Comment: No need to create new class. You can use in the same class. Find out countdown timer tutorial. You can get more tutorials and also good examples for that.

Answer (score 5):

[Frame Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame) will help you

Following snippet will guide you.

```
package com.org.sampleproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1), 1000); //1 Sec
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img2), 1000); //1 Sec 
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img3), 1000); //1 Sec 
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img4), 1000); //1 Sec
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img5), 1000); //1 Sec
        animation.setOneShot(true);

        final ImageView imageAnim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

        animation.start();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageAnim.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                //Perform Your Task Here 

            }
        }, animation.getNumberOfFrames() * 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh good, but I will have to put that the images show when I clicked in the menu inflater. Ej: "Start" and then show the image for 5 second

Comment: OK I'm going to do that. Is there any option to call that method? Because is too long xD

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a CountDownTimer :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

```
protected int [] imgIds = {
R.drawable.img_1,R.drawable.img_2,...
};


new CountDownTimer(12000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
       img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that with this code I show 1 image and I need to show all for 5 seconds